# Can checkboxes execute dynamic PHP on their own, or do I need jquery?

Tags: php, dynamic, checkbox

If I have a checkbox, is it possible to detect whether it is checked or unchecked dynamically in PHP, instead of on submission? Or do I have to go to AJAX/jQuery for that? I have some PHP that I want enacted dynamically if it is checked:

if (isset($_POST['item'])) {
    $var
}

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need an ajax system of some sort. jQuery has great ajax, you could write it manually but you're going to need some form of javascript in order for the request to be made from what I believe.

Answer (score 0):

No, PHP is excuted on the server side, and it's output is sent to the client.

So to execute your PHP code you'll need to use AJAX/jQuery to call your php script when your checkbox's are clicked.